# Convert milliseconds to timestamp with UTC

Tags: java, timestamp, jodatime

I'm trying to convert milliseconds to Timestamp with timezone UTC but it doesn't work as is expected because it convert to my localdatetime.

I have tried following. While debugging the code I have found that when execute this: `new DateTime(eventDate)` it is working properly because it's value is `10:34:18.721` but later new Timestamp() change it to localdatetime.

```
long eventDate = 1566297258721L;
DateTimeZone.setDefault(DateTimeZone.UTC);
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(new DateTime(eventDate).getMillis());
```

I expect to output as:2019-08-20 **10:34:18.721**  but actual output is: 2019-08-20 **12:34:18.721**

Comment: thanks for all responses! I have solved this problem tackling in another way. I have changed at database this field as defining it datatype "long" because it's milliseconds since Unix epoch so whenever i want to use in diffrent timezone i can format this long value.

Comment: That’s the poor solution, sorry. Your database values are quite unreadable after that change and not much worth in ad hoc queries. Which database engine are you using? Java version? Any JPA implementation or the like? PS a `Timestamp` hasn’t got a time zone, but the class is poorly designed and outdated.

Answer (score 4):

You can use **java.time package** of Java 8 and later:

```
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = Instant.ofEpochMilli(1566817891743L).atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you are creating a new DateTime and then get the milliseconds from there, if you already have the milliseconds in the beginning.
Maybe I'm misunderstanding your problem. The milliseconds have nothing to do with the timezone. The timezone is used to compare the same moment in 2 different places and get the respective date. Here are my solutions

### If you want a timestamp from milliseconds:

```
long eventDate = 1566297258721L;
Timestamp time=new Timestamp(eventDate);
System.out.println(time);
```

The result would be `2019-08-20 10:34:18.721` , also the wished SQL format

### If you want to convert a moment from a Timezone to another:

You will get the moment in your actual timezone and transform it in a different one in order to see e.g. what time it was in an other country

```
long eventDate = 1566297258721L;
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(eventDate);
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
```

I hope those snippets could be useful. Happy Programming!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following,

```
long eventDate = 1566297258721L;
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z", Locale.US);
simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
String stringDate = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date(eventDate));
System.out.println(stringDate);
```

It gives me the following output.

> 2019-08-20 10:34:18 UTC